# How do I count the number of rows in a html table from java

Tags: java, html, algorithm

Lets say the table content is in a string, "str"
For example, str is

```
<table>
<tr>
<td>a</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>b</td>
</tr>
</table>
```

counting the number of rows here is trivial, just search the number of "tr" (i cant enter the < and the > here) occurrences.

The problem I am facing is that for the table under consideration, **it may have another table nested inside it.**

In this case, how do I count the number of rows in the parent table?
Another condition BTW, none of the tables have an "id" tag associated with them.

Comment: Use something like [`jSoup`](http://jsoup.org/) to parse the html and it's query capabilities to count the `<tr>` tags...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [jSoup](http://jsoup.org/) library. [Download the jar](http://jsoup.org/download) file, and keep it in your application classpath.

```
  String data = "<table>" +
                "   <tr><td>asdf</td></tr>" +
                "   <tr><td>asdf</td></tr>" +
                "   <tr><td>asdf</td></tr>" +
                "</table>";
   Document document = Jsoup.parse(data, "",  Parser.xmlParser());
   Elements element = document.select("tr.row");
   System.out.println("Number of Rows are : "+element.size());
```

Comment: Will it returns even if it has inner tables ?

Comment: @primitiveType Yes, it will return only the top, parent table row count.